# Function declaration in C using pointers

Tags: c, data-structures

Why does the prototype function declaration start with `*`? This is a code of implementation of data structures from the book by Reema Thareja. Can someone kindly please help me. When switch case is used normal functions are being called by the main function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node
{
     int data;
     struct node *next;
};

struct node *start = NULL;//this type of function declaration
struct node *create_ll(struct node *);
struct node *display(struct node *);
struct node *insert_beg(struct node *);
struct node *insert_end(struct node *);
struct node *insert_before(struct node *);
struct node *insert_after(struct node *);
struct node *delete_beg(struct node *);
struct node *delete_end(struct node *);
struct node *delete_node(struct node *);
struct node *delete_after(struct node *);
struct node *delete_list(struct node *);
struct node *sort_list(struct node *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int option;
    do
    {
       printf("\n\n *****MAIN MENU *****");
       printf("\n 1: Create a list");
       printf("\n 2: Display the list");
       printf("\n 3: Add a node at the beginning");
       printf("\n 4: Add a node at the end");
       printf("\n 5: Add a node before a given node");
       printf("\n 6: Add a node after a given node");
       printf("\n 7: Delete a node from the beginning");
       printf("\n 8: Delete a node from the end");
       printf("\n 9: Delete a given node");
       printf("\n 10: Delete a node after a given node");
       printf("\n 11: Delete the entire list");
       printf("\n 12: Sort the list");
       printf("\n 13: EXIT");
       printf("\n\n Enter your option : ");
       scanf("%d", &option);
       switch(option)
       {
       case 1: start = create_ll(start);
            printf("\n LINKED LIST CREATED");
            break;
       case 2: start = display(start);
            break;
       case 3: start = insert_beg(start);
            break;
       case 4: start = insert_end(start);
            break;
       case 5: start = insert_before(start);
            break;
       case 6: start = insert_after(start);
            break;
       case 7: start = delete_beg(start);
            break;
       case 8: start = delete_end(start);
            break;
       case 9: start = delete_node(start);
            break;
       case 10: start = delete_after(start);
            break;
       case 11: start = delete_list(start);
            printf("\n LINKED LIST DELETED");
            break;
       case 12: start = sort_list(start);
            break;
       }
   }while(option !=13);
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

This are the functions using format of `*` functions. I am including only the first function:

```
   struct node *create_ll(struct node *start)
   {
       struct node *new_node, *ptr;
       int num;
       printf("\n Enter -1 to end");
       printf("\n Enter the data : ");
       scanf("%d", &num);
       while(num!=-1)
       {
       new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       new_node -> data=num;
       if(start==NULL)
       {
       new_node -> next = NULL;
       start = new_node;
       }
       else
       {
       ptr=start;
       while(ptr->next!=NULL)
       ptr=ptr->next;
       ptr->next = new_node;
       new_node->next=NULL;
       }
       printf("\n Enter the data : ");
       scanf("%d", &num);
       }
       return start;
   }

   struct node *display(struct node *start)
   {
       struct node *ptr;
       ptr = start;
       while(ptr != NULL)
       {
       printf("\t %d", ptr -> data);
       ptr = ptr -> next;
       }
       return start;
   }
```

Comment: Please indent your code, at least if you expect someone else to read it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special with these functions except that they return the head of your linked list every time they are invoked.

To make things clear, let's see this scenario: You pass to `create_ll` function (for example) a linked list, you don't pass the whole linked list of course; you just pass the pointer of the first element (node) of the linked list .. that's what we call it head. this function will take the passed pointer and do its job and it'd done it will return a pointer to the first element of the passed linked list (the exact pointer). so simple!

I hope this will make you understand more

Answer (score 0):

The * is part of the return type, not the function name.  The functions return a pointer to a node struct, written in C as

```
struct node *
```